# Illustrator: exporting to PNG makes edges darker

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, anti-aliasing, rasterization

When I export vectors from Illustrator to transparent PNG and bring that image to Photoshop, the edges become darker especially when vector color is light, like white or light gray. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Could there be a black shape behind your white shape? The exact same size and shape as the white object?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exact export settings are, but one likely reason is the *Matte* feature, which defines color to blend transparent pixels against. You will see this in the *Save for Web* dialog box. It has a few options there, what you might need is to set this to *None*.

Answer (score 0):

No idea, what is the reason. But it's possible in Photoshop to shave your image:

- select the transparent area by using the Magic Wand (tolerance = 0, no anti-alias)
- enlargen the selection 1...2 pixels; Select > Modify > Expand
- press Delete