# InDesign: How to prevent darkened anti-aliased edges on placed .ai file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, export, anti-aliasing

I have an Illustrator file with some paths on a transparent background, one of which is a mesh inside a clipping path.

When I place this file inside a InDesign document and export as a PDF, the anti-aliased edges look darkened (similar to [this problem](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82978/illustrator-exporting-to-png-makes-edges-darker)). How can I prevent this?

When I "Save for Web" in Illustrator, I can choose PNG with "Art optimized" and this darkening does not happen. But I can't seem to find this option in InDesign (either on PDF export or during Place/import). Or is there some way to set in the Illustrator file how the clipping group should be anti-aliased?

Any suggestions?

I'm using CS6 btw.

**EDIT:**

So it seems to have to do with the clipping. (The other paths don't have this darkening of the anti-aliased edges.)
Also, the darkening seems to happen apart from InDesign.

Below are some screenshots of:

- the view in Illustrator (zoomed-in version of the screenshot)
- the "Safe for Web" as PNG preview window (Art optimized)
- the "Safe for Web" as PNG preview window (Type optimized)

[image]

Of course, I could export as PNG (Art optimized) and use that inside InDesign. But the resulting export gives a fuzzy image (even when using a high resolution PNG).

Comment: You have no contrl over the antialiasing routines of the PDF viewer

Comment: For other placed Illustrator files, the path anti-aliasing is just fine, so it's not the PDF viewer I think. It seems to be caused by the clipping group/path, since that part has that strange darkening of the anti-aliased edges.

Comment: Well in that case its probably because the file has mutilple lines on top of eachother. Indesign juts passes the file as is and does not do anything for t unless you applcy drop shadows or so. Still technically problem of the pdf viewer

Comment: I double checked, but there's only one mesh/path inside of the clipping group. If I disable the clipping path, all looks fine (except of course the shape). So it seems the clipping itself is the problem. Is there any way I can influence the blending/optimization of the clipping?

Comment: you have no control over how the PDF viewer renders the elements. All PDF renderers are free to choose their rendering algorithm. And if you test another PDF viewer its going to render differently. So even if you miraculously solve this issue it might look shit on another PDF viewer. If you need more control dont use PDF